# iOS - running code on tab change

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have multiple tabs that each does something that may interfere with stuff going on the other tabs if not stopped. In case a user forgets to turn off function in one tab before going to the next tab, I want to know if there is a way to run a block of code from the UIViewController when the user clicks the other tab in the UITabBarController.

Comment: Have you googled this? Have you checked the documentation?

Comment: could you be any less helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement `UITabBarControllerDelegate` protocol in the view controller that has access to the business logic of your stuff. So you can do something when a user tries to click another tab.

It is very likely that you need to implement:

```
 – tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:
 – tabBarController:didSelectViewController:
```

See [documentations](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for UITabBarControllerDelegate.